# how to put a echo of text type input's id in a variable in php

Tags: php

I'm facing a problem in this code:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $num; $x++) {
    $row8= mysqli_fetch_array($result8);
       echo "<td><input id='".$row['StudentID'].'['. $row8['MarksID']."]' name='".$row['StudentID'].'['. $row8['MarksID']."]' type='text'></td>";
    $marksID[$x]=$row8['MarksID'];
    $count++;
    // $ID[$count]=?;
```

I want to put the id as a variable (`<input id='".$row['StudentID'].'['. $row8['MarksID']."]' name='".$row['StudentID'].'['. $row8['MarksID']."]' type='text'>`) so that I could use the value of that input in sql query. How could I keep the id in a variable?

Comment: Explain further

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to describe.

Comment: updated; is it ok to understand now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questions is not that clear.

Is this what you are looking for:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

**EDIT** - After your explanation

I am still not sure if i fully understood. but are looking for something like this.

```
$ID[$count]= "$row['StudentID'].'['.$row8['MarksID'].']'
```

so lets say the `count = 0` initially and `$row['StudentID'] = 1` and `$row8['MarksID'] = 2` in the first iteration
so `$ID[$count]` is `$ID[1]`

`$ID[1]` will be equal to `1[2]`

`$ID[1] = "1[2]"`

Comment: Hey. How's it going. Has my edit answer helped. Or have i still miss understood the question.